# MySQL slave replication not writing binlog file

Tags: mysql, database, replication, database-replication, multi-master-replication

I have installed 3 MySQL Server (8.0.29-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) to create a master-slave replication like

Master -> Slave -> Secondary Slave

My issue is when i change database in master it is replicated in Slave by binlog writen by Master
but that change done on Slave is not getting replicated on Secondary Slave

i have enabled log_slave_updates / log_replica_updates in slave but nothing worked.

```
[mysqld]

# bind-address          = 127.0.0.1
server-id               = 4
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_expire_logs_seconds      = 2592000
max_binlog_size   = 100M
binlog_do_db            = replication_db_1
binlog_do_db            = replication_db_2
relay-log = /var/lib/mysql/ubuntu-vm8-relay-bin.log

log_slave_updates
log_replica_updates
# binlog_ignore_db      = include_database_name
```

Same thing happens for circular Master Master Replication with 3 servers,
create database xxxxx; alone replicating all 3 nodes, but not table creation query getting replicated more than one level of hierarchy.

```
mysql> show global variables like "%log%";
+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                                  | Value                                     |
+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| activate_all_roles_on_login                    | OFF                                       |
| back_log                                       | 151                                       |
| binlog_cache_size                              | 32768                                     |
| binlog_checksum                                | CRC32                                     |
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates        | OFF                                       |
| binlog_encryption                              | OFF                                       |
| binlog_error_action                            | ABORT_SERVER                              |
| binlog_expire_logs_auto_purge                  | ON                                        |
| binlog_expire_logs_seconds                     | 2592000                                   |
| binlog_format                                  | MIXED                                     |
| binlog_group_commit_sync_delay                 | 0                                         |
| binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count        | 0                                         |
| binlog_gtid_simple_recovery                    | ON                                        |
| binlog_max_flush_queue_time                    | 0                                         |
| binlog_order_commits                           | ON                                        |
| binlog_rotate_encryption_master_key_at_startup | OFF                                       |
| binlog_row_event_max_size                      | 8192                                      |
| binlog_row_image                               | FULL                                      |
| binlog_row_metadata                            | MINIMAL                                   |
| binlog_row_value_options                       |                                           |
| binlog_rows_query_log_events                   | OFF                                       |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size                         | 32768                                     |
| binlog_transaction_compression                 | OFF                                       |
| binlog_transaction_compression_level_zstd      | 3                                         |
| binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size     | 25000                                     |
| binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking         | COMMIT_ORDER                              |
| expire_logs_days                               | 0                                         |
| general_log                                    | OFF                                       |
| general_log_file                               | /var/lib/mysql/ubuntu-vm8.log             |
| innodb_api_enable_binlog                       | OFF                                       |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout                    | 1                                         |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit                 | 1                                         |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                         | 16777216                                  |
| innodb_log_checksums                           | ON                                        |
| innodb_log_compressed_pages                    | ON                                        |
| innodb_log_file_size                           | 50331648                                  |
| innodb_log_files_in_group                      | 2                                         |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir                      | ./                                        |
| innodb_log_spin_cpu_abs_lwm                    | 80                                        |
| innodb_log_spin_cpu_pct_hwm                    | 50                                        |
| innodb_log_wait_for_flush_spin_hwm             | 400                                       |
| innodb_log_write_ahead_size                    | 8192                                      |
| innodb_log_writer_threads                      | ON                                        |
| innodb_max_undo_log_size                       | 1073741824                                |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size               | 134217728                                 |
| innodb_print_ddl_logs                          | OFF                                       |
| innodb_redo_log_archive_dirs                   |                                           |
| innodb_redo_log_encrypt                        | OFF                                       |
| innodb_undo_log_encrypt                        | OFF                                       |
| innodb_undo_log_truncate                       | ON                                        |
| log_bin                                        | ON                                        |
| log_bin_basename                               | /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin                  |
| log_bin_index                                  | /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.index            |
| log_bin_trust_function_creators                | OFF                                       |
| log_bin_use_v1_row_events                      | OFF                                       |
| log_error                                      | /var/log/mysql/error.log                  |
| log_error_services                             | log_filter_internal; log_sink_internal    |
| log_error_suppression_list                     |                                           |
| log_error_verbosity                            | 2                                         |
| log_output                                     | FILE                                      |
| log_queries_not_using_indexes                  | ON                                        |
| log_raw                                        | OFF                                       |
| log_replica_updates                            | ON                                        |
| log_slave_updates                              | ON                                        |
| log_slow_admin_statements                      | OFF                                       |
| log_slow_extra                                 | OFF                                       |
| log_slow_replica_statements                    | OFF                                       |
| log_slow_slave_statements                      | OFF                                       |
| log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog               | ON                                        |
| log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes         | 0                                         |
| log_timestamps                                 | UTC                                       |
| max_binlog_cache_size                          | 18446744073709547520                      |
| max_binlog_size                                | 104857600                                 |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size                     | 18446744073709547520                      |
| max_relay_log_size                             | 0                                         |
| relay_log                                      | /var/lib/mysql/ubuntu-vm8-relay-bin.log   |
| relay_log_basename                             | /var/lib/mysql/ubuntu-vm8-relay-bin       |
| relay_log_index                                | /var/lib/mysql/ubuntu-vm8-relay-bin.index |
| relay_log_info_file                            | relay-log.info                            |
| relay_log_info_repository                      | TABLE                                     |
| relay_log_purge                                | ON                                        |
| relay_log_recovery                             | OFF                                       |
| relay_log_space_limit                          | 0                                         |
| slow_query_log                                 | ON                                        |
| slow_query_log_file                            | /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log             |
| sql_log_off                                    | OFF                                       |
| sync_binlog                                    | 1                                         |
| sync_relay_log                                 | 10000                                     |
| sync_relay_log_info                            | 10000                                     |
| terminology_use_previous                       | NONE                                      |
+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
90 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Slave 1 :

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for source to send event
                  Master_Host: 192.168.203.88
                  Master_User: replicator
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000002
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 157
               Relay_Log_File: ubuntu-vm8-relay-bin.000006
                Relay_Log_Pos: 373
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000002
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 157
              Relay_Log_Space: 635
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: 0f426665-12fa-11ed-b411-080027e54a70
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Replica has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version: 
       Master_public_key_path: 
        Get_master_public_key: 1
            Network_Namespace: 
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Slave 2 (secondary slave )

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for source to send event
                  Master_Host: 192.168.202.120
                  Master_User: replicator
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000002
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 157
               Relay_Log_File: ubuntu-vm7-relay-bin.000005
                Relay_Log_Pos: 326
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000002
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 157
              Relay_Log_Space: 757
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 4
                  Master_UUID: d2dc13dc-12f9-11ed-b7d6-080027d93010
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Replica has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version: 
       Master_public_key_path: 
        Get_master_public_key: 1
            Network_Namespace: 
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do both slaves/replicas have unique `server-id`s?

Comment: yes, each have unique one, 1,2,3 for 3 nodes

Comment: Why have you set `binlog_do_db`? Note the limits in docs about replication filtering. If you want a full copy, remove the setting. What does `show slave status` show.  Edit the question with details.

Comment: i wanted to do changes for only certain databases [replication_db_1, replication_db_2], hence i added those two alone in binlog_do_db. also changes done to table in those databases are reflected in slave 1, it is not replicated to secondary slave from slave. have added show slave status out put in question

Comment: Are the default databases the default when they are updated? See [binlog-do-db](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-do-db). If you look at the binary logs with `mysqlbinlog` does it show the transactions you have issued?

Comment: i can see binlog writes in master node, then that binlog is read from slave 1 and replicating in it, but now that slave 1 is not writing binlog file, so that the secondary slave connected to the slave 1 cannot replicate the change made from master.

Comment: thanks dan, it seems binlog_do_db was the issue, after i commented binlog_do_db, changes made on table also refelected on all nodes in linear chain replication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add `binlog_do_db` in `mysql.conf`, only database level changes like `create database xxx` and `drop database xxx` only affected in all 3 mysql servers [Master - Master - Master], table level changes are not affecting for the 2 level of the triangular master master replication setup

just comment out `binlod_do_db`, and restart the mysql

all the database level, table level changes gets affected in all 3 node in the replication group

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-do-db